# How to link X11 to qt project on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, qt, x11, dlib

I try to compile Qt project using dlib

```
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/dnn.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/clustering.h>
#include <dlib/string.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    matrix <rgb_pixel> image;
    load_image(image, "/Users/ivanlebedev/Desktop/Projects/ManSearch/cars/2.jpg");
    image_window win(image);
}
```

but i have this ERROR:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.15/include/dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:12: ошибка: "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
#error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
 ^
```

How i can make my program work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nor want x11-anything. You need to compile dlib without x11 support, and then it'll work fine.